# How to do a "Dummy" ORDER BY in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM blah1 WHERE blah2 ORDERBY %s
```

where I substitute a (sanitized!) string for `%s`. The problem is, the string might be empty. How do I insert a no-op in there if the string is empty, instead of changing the rest of the query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it should work for you: `ORDER BY NULL`

Answer (score 1):

A fixed string or number (`1`,`0`, `'noop'`) <= do sent it *with* the quotes.

Comment: `order by 1` will actually sort by the first column in some sql implementations.

Comment: Good to know, will note that, any hint as to which for example? Doesn't in MySQL though.

Comment: In Postgres, this will work for instance: `select a from unnnest(array[3,1,2]) a order by 1;` (returns 1, 2, 3).